# Docker nginx, epxress Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED docker bridge network

Tags: angular, docker, express, nginx

so i was dockerizing my frontend, backend and the database.
the database and the backend talk with each other.
the frontend and the backend behave to akward.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wVO2.png)

**curl backend:3000 works
**ping backend:3000 works

talking directly to NodeJS/Express via postman leads to

```
`GET http://backend:3000/read-events%20
GET http://backend:3000/readVendor`
```

what so ever.. once the backend wasnt dockerized it worked.
assuming it has to do with cors.. well i allowed all origins.. all methods.. all everyting..

it's assigned with the right name rigth hostname it's part of the docker network

the logs on my backend dont even show that there is anything going on.
meaning with the convetional ways.. http.get on baseURL+route it is not reachable. I suspect nginx is adding headers or causing the problem but my research so far only tell no. gninx doesnt ad ustom headers by default unless its told to.

ok . so i deleted the configs default configs just make sure sure..
i came up with a new default.conf. things worked fine.. until i went cross domain..

dockerfile for angular/nginx:

```
FROM node:14 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN echo "server {" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
 && echo "    listen 80;" >> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
 && echo "    listen 3000;" >> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
 && echo "    server_name frontend;" >> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
 && echo "    location / {" >> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
 && echo "        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;" >> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
 && echo "        index  index.html;" >> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
 && echo "        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.html;" >> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
# && echo "        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';" >> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
 && echo "    }" >> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
 && echo "}" >> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY dist/frontend /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80 3000 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

the node dockerfile for express is way simpler:

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /any
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./dist/* ./dist/
EXPOSE 3000 27017 80 443
CMD [ "node", "/any/dist/index.js" ]
```

the docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  database:
    build:
        context: ./database 
        dockerfile: dockerfile
    container_name: database
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    networks:
      - world
  
  backend:
    build:
        context: ./backend
        dockerfile: dockerfile
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: always
    networks:
      - world
    depends_on:
      - database

  frontend:
    build:
        context: ./frontend
        dockerfile: dockerfile
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    networks:
      - world
    depends_on:
      - backend
  
networks:
  world:
```

im a bit clue less or simply blind. i feel like tried everything.
i quadruple checked things.. please feel free to ask if u have an idea that requires more information to be shared

i tried to keep it short and on point

before i forget the errors itself :

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

and

```
    ERROR lRerror: ProgressEventisTrusted: truebubbles: falsecancelBubble: falsecancelable: falsecomposed: falsecurrentTarget: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: 'http://backend:3000/read-events', __zone_symbol__loadfalse: null, __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__timeoutfalse: null, …}defaultPrevented: falseeventPhase: 0lengthComputable: falseloaded: 0returnValue: truesrcElement: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: 'http://backend:3000/read-events', __zone_symbol__loadfalse: null, __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__timeoutfalse: null, …}target: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: 'http://backend:3000/read-events', __zone_symbol__loadfalse: null, __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__timeoutfalse: null, …}timeStamp: 2618.5total: 0type: "error"[[Prototype]]: ProgressEventheaders: poheaders: Map(0) {size: 0}lazyUpdate: nullnormalizedNames: Map(0) {size: 0}[[Prototype]]: Objectmessage: "Http failure response for http://backend:3000/read-events: 0 Unknown Error"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 0statusText: "Unknown Error"url: "http://backend:3000/read-events"[[Prototype]]: kE
handleError @ main.60b0411221324373.js:1
```

the main problem is i have no clue what the error tell me beyond what is written there. i cannot interpret or conclude more than i have tried

i also flushed dns
.. which would be more suitable for host type of docker networks

im running out of ideas.

so further more i was reading stackoverflow articles and questions.
i cannot fully exclude that it is a preflight issue.. but to be fully fair here i only faced it once and it looked different.

can someone verify or exclude??

UPDATE: when make GETS from my the client/angular/as input on the website it return http 304 0 in the logs
of the nginx container

304 is not modified . its about stauts changing and changing resources. can that be pre-flight related?

does pre-flight necessarily have a reference to cors in them?

UPDATE: i added proxy_pass backendURL to the nginx config. now the log in the frontend has changed to 111 connection refused...

and the error 502 bad gateway

i still have no clue whats going on

Comment: Your front-end application runs in the browser, even if its code is served from a container.  Since it's not running in a container, it can't use Docker networking and can't resolve the Docker-internal host names.  If you set up your Nginx configuration to also proxy the back-end, you can use a path-only URL to call it, which avoids CORS issues as well.

Comment: sounds awsome! i need moment to process and research. thanks for keeping me on track!

Comment: so is it setting up another nginx container? that would just bypass information? I think i dont get the concept fully.

Comment: u mean not the frontend server is performing the request but me as the client from outside the docker container and network is requesting and trying to display the backend -info. i completely lack on an idea of how i could implement a proxy server inside the docker network to solve it. would i use the docker nertwork's gateway for that?

Comment: In the linked question, I describe two approaches: either connect the front-end container directly to the back-end's published `ports:`, or set up a reverse proxy to handle both.  The browser will never be on the Docker network and can't directly see the Docker-network host names.  (In fact, you can safely delete the `networks:` blocks in your existing Compose file with no other changes.)

Comment: I'm reading your linked post. I tried to bypass then it loads the content into to browser and doesn't let the front-end process it no more besides it only work for the base url on the backend

Comment: so i ve been thinking alot.